# How to calculate inclusion probability under sampling without replacement

Tags: sampling

I am quite new to sampling method.

The task is sampling without replacement with unequal probabilities, but I have problem in calculating inclusion probability.

I want to sample $n$ units from the population of size $N$ through the following procedure in the figure. After the procedure, I need to calculate the inclusion probability in order to get the Horvits-Tompson estimator, an unbiased estimator of the Population Total.

But I don't know how to calculate inclusion probability, because I need to traverse $n!\binom{N-1}{n-1}$ n-tuples (e.g. add the probability of $50!\binom{999}{49}$ n-tuples), it's huge and not realistic!!!

My ultimate goal is to have an unbiased estimator of the Population Total, based on $p_i(k)$ constructed by myself.

How can I do this?

[image]
[image]

The inclusion probability is also written as the following $p(u_i)$:

$p(i) = \sum_{(i_1, i_2, ..., i_n)\in S(i)}{p(i_1, i_2, ..., i_n)}$
where $S(i)$ is consisting of n-tuples where unit $i$ and other $(n-1)$ different units . There are $n!\binom{N-1}{n-1}$ elements in $S(i)$!

The formula is from paper: SAMPLING WITH VARYING PROBABILITIES WITHOUT REPLACEMENT: ROTATING AND NON-ROTATING SAMPLES.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use an algorithm that selects each unit (without replacement) with a user determined probability. Usually this probability is proportionate to some measure of size. There are many such algorithms. Hanif and Brewer list fifty in their [1980 review article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1403257). Several of these algorithms (as well as newer algorithms) are implemented in the [sampling](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampling/sampling.pdf) package in R. See the functions that begin with the prefix "UP" for unequal probability.

Note that the 'sample()' function in base R does not actually sample with a user determined probability if the 'prob' argument is set and sampling is without replacement. This is a sequential algorithm and, as noted above, using such an algorithm can make it very difficult to, post facto, determine the probabilities of inclusion.

Comment: I had a look at Brewer & Hanif (1983), but I do not yet see why there are so many different methods of sampling _without_ replacement. I see B&H classify the various algorithms in equivalence classes, but there still seem to be many different classes. Why is there not just 'one ultimate' method of sampling without replacement? I am missing some intuition here, and therefore struggling to follow the mathematics.

Comment: Hmm. There's not  "one ultimate method" because as you note in your original question, the straightforward approach is computational intractably in all but the most trivial cases. Some methods work well in some cases but not in others, e.g. some form of rejection sampling can work well if you only want to draw 2 or 3 units from a large $n$ but becomes intractable if you want to draw a large fraction of $n$. Maybe this is a better introduction: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574013722000673?via%3Dihub